# JQuery CSS method doesn't change the height element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

I have a grid with some elements. These elements has the class `item` . When I do click in one of them, I toogle the `expand` to resize this element.

```
  <body>
        <div class="grid">
              <a href="#">
                    <div class="item" style="background-image: url('https://i.giphy.com/l0NwI1oBNxYfoRRny.gif'); height: 270px; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute;">
                    </div>
              </a>   
              <a href="#">
                    <div class="item" style="background-image: url('https://i.giphy.com/pYI1hSqUdcBiw.gif'); height: 202px; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute;">
                    </div>
              </a>   
              <a href="#">
                    <div class="item" style="background-image: url('https://i.giphy.com/l3vR58nYgtIUKua1G.gif'); height: 149px; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute;">
                    </div>
              </a>   
              <a href="#">
                    <div class="item" style="background-image: url('https://i.giphy.com/3o7abxtmPxanzaESGY.gif'); height: 202px; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute;">
                    </div>
              </a>   
               ...
        </div>
  </body>
```

**CSS**

```
.item {
  color: white;
  display: table;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 270px;

}

.expand {
  transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s, left 0.5s, top 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s, left 0.5s, top 0.5s;
  height: 100% ;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0 !important;
  top: 0 ;
  z-index: 99;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

**JS**

```
  $('.item').click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass('expand');
 });
```

So, the `width` resizes to the 100% of parent size (`grid`) but the `height`
doesn't changes.

This is the grid view before click on any item element

[image: This is the grid view before click on any item element]

After clicking on the third element

[image: After clicking on the third element]

So, here is the problem: In the same JS method I tried to add:

```
  $('.item').click(function () {
         var height = $(this).height();
         var width = $(this).width();
         var act = $(this).hasClass("expand");
         if(act){
             $('.expand').css('height',Math.floor($('.grid').width()  * height / width) + 'px !important');
             $('.expand').css('width','50% !important');
       }
}
```

But the `height` and `width` don't change. So, by some reason this `$('.expand').css()` method is not adding the new values.

Answer (score 1):

Because you've defined `height` as an inline style to `.item` and an inline style will overwrite styles from an external stylesheet. Either move that `height` to `.item` or use `!important` with `height` in `.expand`

```js
$(".item").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("expand");
});
```

```css
.item {
  color: white;
  display: table;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 270px;
}

.expand {
  transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s, left 0.5s, top 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s, left 0.5s, top 0.5s;
  height: 100% !important;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0 !important;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="item" style="height: 202px; background-image: url('https://i.giphy.com/3o7abxtmPxanzaESGY.gif'); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute;">
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="item" style="height: 202px; background-image: url('https://i.giphy.com/3o7abxtmPxanzaESGY.gif');  background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute;">
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="item" style="height: 202px; background-image: url('https://i.giphy.com/3o7abxtmPxanzaESGY.gif'); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute;">
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="item" style="height: 202px; background-image: url('https://i.giphy.com/3o7abxtmPxanzaESGY.gif');  background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute;">
      </div>
    </a>
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The problem is that each `item` element must have  defined the height in inline style. I tried to do that  `$('.expand').css('height',Math.floor($('.grid').width()  * height / width) + 'px !important');` but doesn't work. If I try this `!important` on the `width` it doesn't work too `$('.expand').css('width','50% !important');`.

Comment: @AlbertoCrespo `!important` works just fine - updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove inline style `height: 202px;` from div.item and add `height: 202px` to css class `.item`

Inline style has more weight than your stylesheet. That's why `height: 100%` in .expand is not applied.

http://monc.se/kitchen/38/cascading-order-and-inheritance-in-css

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe it will be better to assign in CSS the pointer, instead of using the `<a>` it can be part of the problem...

Second, you could have a hidden `div` Height:100% Width:100% that loads the image and then appears on top of all the others displaying it.

```
<body>
    <div id="showDiv"></div>
    <div class="grid">
       <div class="item" style="background-image: url('https://i.giphy.com/3o7abxtmPxanzaESGY.gif'); height: 202px; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute;"></div>
       <div class="item" style="background-image: url('https://i.giphy.com/3o7abxtmPxanzaESGY.gif'); height: 202px; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute;"></div>
       <div class="item" style="background-image: url('https://i.giphy.com/3o7abxtmPxanzaESGY.gif'); height: 202px; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute;"></div>
           ...
    </div>
</body>
```

Then

```
 $('.item').click(function () {
     var img = $(this).css("background-image");
     $('#showDiv').css({'background-image':img});
     $('#showDiv').show();
   }
}
$("#showDiv").click(function(){
     $(this).hide();
     $('#showDiv').css({'background-image':""});
});
```

And style showDiv

```
 #showDiv{
     display:none;
     height: 100%;
     widht: 100%;
     z-index: 999;
 }
```

This is an option that won't mess up your page every time...